# Reading duplicate XML elements into a string array using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a javascript/jquery newbie. I have an XML file that has duplicate elements such as the aka elements in this example:

```
<marker>
   <name>Aberdeen Army Airfield</name>
   <aka>Saunders Field</aka>
   <aka>Aberdeen Regional Airport</aka>
   <address>Aberdeen, South Dakota</address>
</marker>
```

When I read these duplicate elements into a variable, they concatenate when I use this code:

```
MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
    $.get(filename, function(xml){
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
           var name    = $(this).find('name').text();
           var aka     = $(this).find('aka').text();
           var address = $(this).find('address').text();
           }
...
}
```

The variable aka contains "Saunders FieldAberdeen Regional Airport".
How can I read the duplicate elements such that the variable is a string array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
    $.get(filename, function(xml){
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
           var name    = $(this).find('name').text();
           var aka     = $(this).find('aka').map(function(i,v){
                                   return ($(v).text());
                         }).get();
           var address = $(this).find('address').text();
           }
...
}
```

It's working here.
https://jsfiddle.net/hnfLgm7m/
If it's what you want, make sure you press the tick next to this answer.

[image]